# Pass array for GET data in GuzzlePHP

Tags: php, guzzle

Is it possible to pass an array of data for `GET` request in GuzzlePHP Client?

I've found nothing in documentation and on Stack Overflow.

i.e this does not work as I expect:

```
// first level of this array is refered as
// request settings: headers, redirects, etc.
$array = [
    'this will be rendered as request settings',
    'data' => [
        'var1' => 'value1',
        'var4' => 'value4',
    ],
];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', '/redirect/3', $array);
```

---

**Edit:** For all those who can't understand the problem:

GET parameters are not passed in this request, thus I only get this URL structure:

```
http://host/redirect/3
```

Expected:

```
http://host/redirect/3?var1=value1&var4=value4
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Who mentioned any errors?

Comment: Read the question again. Thanks.

Comment: which guzzle version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it finally. Settings key is `query` If [anyone else](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#making-a-request) needs it:

```
$params = [
    'var1' => 'value1',
    'var4' => 'value4',
];

$client->request('GET', '/redirect/3', [
    'query' => $params
]);
```

This finally transforms the URL of my request into:

```
/redirect/3?var1=value1&var4=value4
```

Answer (score 4):

If you open a manual, for example, http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters, you will see that query parameters should be send under `query` key. So your array should be:

```
$array = [
    'this will be rendered as request settings',
    'query' => [
        'var1' => 'value1',
        'var4' => 'value4',
    ],
];
```

Comment: I've posted my answer seconds after yours. I'll accept your answer. Thanks.